# Дан массив целых чисел, который может содержать повторяющиеся элементы . Получить все числа, которые входят в массив по одному разу

Tags: c, массивы

Проблема в том,что я не понимаю,как поставить условие,чтобы часть повторяющихся чисел исключалась и не выводилась.

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>
      #include <conio.h>
      int main (void)
      {int n;
        printf("a[n],n=...\n");//число элементов в массиве
        scanf("%i",&n);
        int a[n];
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)//задание значений каждого из элементов
        {
      printf("number %i=",i);
      scanf("%i",&a[i]);
        }
           for(i=0; i<n; i++)//вывод массива
            {        
          printf("%d ", a[i]);
            }
       getch(); 
          return 0;
      }
```

Comment: Когда получаешь массив элементов и записываешь их в другой массив(в котором не должны повторяться целые числа), делай проверку вносимого числа со всеми числами внутри массива на то, что оно не равно одному из них, соответственно, если не равно, то вносишь, а если равно, то рассматриваешь новое число

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, раз у вас только те, которые входят один раз - это куда проще, чем те, которые входят многократно :)

Как я понимаю, на этом уровне вас не очень интересует эффективность, так что будем действовать незатейливо. Просто каждое число (как их перебрать? да циклом же) сравниваем со всеми остальными и смотрим - а нет ли такого же? Если нет - значит, выводим.

А как сравнить со всеми остальными? Опять же циклом. Только надо не забыть, что число всегда равно самому себе, и отдельно обрабатывать этот случай.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)           // "Для всех чисел"
{
    int dbl = 0;                     // Считаем, что дубля нет
    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)       // "Со всеми другими числами"
    {
        if (a[i] == a[j] && i != j)  // i != j - чтоб не проверять равенство самому себе
        {
            dbl = 1;                 // О, есть такое число? Запомним этот факт
            break;                   // Дальше проверять незачем
        }
    }
    if (!dbl) printf("%d ",a[i]);    // Дублей не было? тогда выводим...
}
```

Comment: вы прямо мой ангел-хранитель))))) на все мои вопросы отвечаете ,спасибо. Однако мне опять обидно,поскольку я был близок к решению.Я догадывался ,что нужно было использовать цикл внутри цикла , даже букву ту же самую использовал j(ну ,наверное, также сделал бы любой , кто занимался векторной алгеброй с этой тройкой векторов i j k ), но все же я не смог задать правильное условие выхода из цикла, а посему и обратился с вопросом.P.S.прошу прощения,если пишу сумбурно,я всегда на эмоциях,когда удается решить задачу,которая долго не поддавалась решению.